# How to get a data for a perticular logged in user ( through API)?

Tags: api, extension, php

I gave an ACL role to users for data segregation. I want to fetch data from database but data must filter i.e. ACL. How to get data. Also I want a userkey and sitekey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you will need to send api key of the logged in user who access is limited by ACL (also check_permission = 1 in api params).

Comment: I tried but it gives me an error. 
error_message: "Failed to authenticate key". I also provide a api key and site key then it gives me a error. error_message "ERROR: No CMS user associated with given api-key"

Comment: How to get api key of user?

Comment: this error occurs if the the logged user doesn't have api key. You need to have api key for all user. Api key is only required when using rest api

Comment: How to get a user key using php?